# Bootstrap 4 data-slide-to not working

Tags: bootstrap-4

According to Bootstrap's documentation, I should be able to target a specific slide in a carousel and go to that slide with the data-slide-to attribute. I've fixed up a quick example here:  https://codepen.io/alemieux/pen/mqzVML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-slide-to="0">
Go to First Slide
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-slide-to="1">
Go to Second Slide
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-slide-to="2">
Go to Third Slide
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModal" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-body">
         <!-- Carousel with controls -->
         <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
               <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <h1>This is the first slide</h1>
                  <p>The content of slide 1</p>
               </div>
               <div class="carousel-item">
                  <h1>This is the Second slide</h1>
                  <p>The content of slide 2</p>
               </div>
               <div class="carousel-item">
                  <h1>This is the Third slide</h1>
                  <p>The content of slide 3</p>
               </div>
               <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
               <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
               </a>
               <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
               <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- End Carousel -->
      </div>
      <button type="bottom" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

But it's not working. The carousel is inside a modal and I'm wondering if that's the issue.

Comment: I think it doesn't work because the button targets the modal, not the carousel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the `data-slide-to` attribute was designed to be used on `<ol>` items inside the main carousel tag. However, with a little javascript you can make it work:

```
$('button[data-slide-to]').on('click', function(){
    $('#carouselExampleControls').carousel($(this).data('slide-to'));
});
```

Also, I would consider to set `data-interval="false"` on the carousel tag in order to stop the automatic cycling.

UPDATE: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dferenc/pen/VrEWzv)

Comment: @Klooven Did you check the Pen example? It definitely works, as the solution adds an additional click listener to the buttons. That callback then slides the carousel to the position stored in the `data-slide-to` attribute of the clicked button. But you are right in that the buttons are targeting the modal in the first place.

Comment: I did find a JavaScript workaround and I do think you're right Klooven, that the data-slide-to works inside the carousel and not outside: $("#gotoSlide1").click(function(){
        $("#carousel").carousel(0);
    });