# .active class on custom bootstrap carousel control

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am creating a carousel with custom control in bootstrap 4. 
I have managed to slide carousel according to custom control. Now problem I am facing is it's not showing the active class on active control.

Here is my Bootstrap 4 Carousel HTML Code:

```
<div id="introslider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="control">
                        <a class="btn btn-control active" href="#introslider" data-slide-to="0">Welcome</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-control" href="#introslider" data-slide-to="1">Test </a>
                        <a class="btn btn-control" href="#introslider" data-slide-to="2">Test 2</a>
                    </div>
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/200x400" alt="First slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h3>Welcome</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/200x400" alt="First slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h3>Test</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/200x400" alt="First slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h3>Test 2</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#introslider {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#introslider .carousel-caption p {
    text-align: left;
}
#introslider .carousel-caption {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}

#introslider .control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#introslider .carousel-inner {
    position: static;
}

#introslider .carousel-item {
    margin-top: 45px;
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: not displaying .active class]

Do you guys have any idea how can I make it work?

Comment: Could it help you:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539162/bootstrap-4-data-slide-to-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539162/bootstrap-4-data-slide-to-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code will help you.

```css
#introslider {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#introslider .carousel-caption p {
    text-align: left;
}
#introslider .carousel-caption {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}

#introslider .control {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right: 0;
}

#introslider .carousel-inner {
    position: static;
}

#introslider .carousel-item {
    margin-top: 45px;
}

#introslider .control .btn.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="introslider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="control carousel-indicators">
                        <a class="btn btn-control active" href="#introslider" data-slide-to="0">Welcome</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-control" href="#introslider" data-slide-to="1">Test </a>
                        <a class="btn btn-control" href="#introslider" data-slide-to="2">Test 2</a>
                    </div>
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/200x400" alt="First slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h3>Welcome</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/200x400" alt="First slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h3>Test</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/200x400" alt="First slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h3>Test 2</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```